# Delete cache folder in Flash Builder mobile android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, caching, flash-builder

is there a way for me to delete the cache folder on the device my app is deployed on?

I would like to delete these folders if possible,

```
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/.AIR 
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/webviewCache 
/data/data/air.<appID>/databases
```

Basically I need to clear those folders because the AS3 Facebook library is having trouble logging users out, and the only other way to log a user out when needed is by clearing the applications cache.

I am developing on a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tab, running Honeycomb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'Settings -> Applications ->  -> remove application data' (or something like that - I've got Android 2.2, Polish version)?

Comment: I need to remove it programmatically at specific intervals in my application, so clearing the data outside of the application is not really an option. But thanks!